# RegEx to match against HTML tags with certain attributes

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I’m trying to write a RegEx that matches an opening HTML tag with a `class` attribute on it. Just like the following:

```
<!-- these should match -->
<div class=" 
<div class=">
<img src="image.jpg" class="
<img src="image.jpg" class=">

<!-- these should not match -->
<div> class="
</div class=">
```

So far I have:

```
<[^/^>]+>
```

This matches any opening HTML tag. I’m looking to adapt it to look for a `class` attribute within there too, like in the examples above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<[[a-z]{1,} class=">?
```

This is a really simple and will only match your examples. If you want to catch any opening tag with a class attribute in any place, you'll have to do something more complex.

Also, I like to use this:
https://regex101.com/

For testing online regex, a pretty helpful little playground.

Comment: Ah, you raise a good point about my match examples being very simple. I have edited my question with a slightly different set of matches. How would I adjust the RegEx to match those too?

Comment: You might need to chain them. First find all tags, then match within them for class . <[[a-z]{1,} +([a-z]{1,}=["'].*["'])?  *[\/]?>    That may find you html tags, but then you'll have to do another operation to look for a class, something like class=['"].*['"]   . This is javascript regex, what language are you using to actually process the html?

Comment: Oh thank you. I’m using JavaScript to read the HTML as a unescaped/unsanitized string.

Comment: Happy to help. I can't promise how reliable this will be... there's a lot of stuff on SO about regex html tag matching so you may want to do some more testing on this to make sure this is really the best approach before putting this into production.

Comment: You should escape the first square bracket like `\[` in order to get this regex working.